# Advice: SQL Joining multiple tables with into a single view

Tags: sql

I have multiple SQL Server asset sources which I want to to combine into a single `Asset` table, which will store some basic info, plus the where the Asset came from. each table has a different amount of columns, but we are only interested in a small number of columns.
Each datasource has about 2-3k rows.

Pseudo code

```
select name, os, user, source 
from tblLSAssets 

and insert into TblALL

if tblAZ.name exists in tblAll 
    update that row with tblAll.source +="AZ" (or use separate col)

if tblAZ.name does NOT exists in tblAll 
    add a new row to tblAll with tblAZ.name, tblAZ.os etc. update source col.
```

Repeat for each Asset source.

I'm quite happy to have multiple columns for each data source if this is easier.

I've tried this in code enumerating each table but this is quite slow. and wondered if their was some SQL magic that could make this a little quicker.

tblLSAssets:

| name | OS | user | colx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | Win | user1 | bla |
| PC2 | Lin | user2 | bla |
| PC3 | Win | user3 | bla |
| PC4 | Mac | user4 | bla |

tblAZ

| name | OS | user | colx | coly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | Win | user1 | bla | bla |
| PC20 | OS | user20 | bla | bla |
| PC30 | Xt | user30 | bla | bla |

tblAll

| name | OS | user | source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | Win | user1 | LS+AZ |
| PC20 | OS | user2 | AZ |
| PC30 | Xt | user3 | AZ |
| PC4 | Mac | user4 | LS |

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to write a [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement for each table to populate your `tblAll`. This could also be solved using a UNION with `STRING_AGG()` to bring it all together, which you could just toss into a view and not store all of your data twice.

Comment: Welcome! I would advice you to read ["How to write a title that summarizes the specific problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned MERGE in the comments and if each of these source/asset tables are being loaded by a process, including a MERGE statement after the data is in inserted into its asset table would be the most appropriate way to keep `tblAll` updated.

Otherwise, if this is a one-time thing, or if you want to avoid storing your data twice and just create a view, you could use a UNION and [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
SELECT name, OS, user, STRING_AGG(source, '+') as source 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT name, OS, user, 'LS' as source FROM tableLS
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, OS, user, 'AZ' FROM tableAZ
        UNION ALL
        SELECT name, OS, user, 'NA' FROM tableNA
    )
GROUP BY name, OS, user;
```